# Crashing the application when Run on IOS 5.0 by clicking the table view;

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5

i have done the code to show the fading of the cell when click on the Division, the code works well for the IOS 3.0 and 4.o
  the code looks like

```
- (NSArray*)indexPathsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
      NSMutableArray *paths = [NSMutableArray array];
      NSInteger row;

  for ( row = 0; row < [self numberOfRowsInSection:section]; row++ )
          {
    [paths addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:section]];
      }

  return [NSArray arrayWithArray:paths];
}
- (void)toggle:(BOOL*)isExpanded section:(NSInteger)section {
       *isExpanded = !*isExpanded;


    [Table beginUpdates];
    if ( !*isExpanded ) 
       {  
         NSArray *paths = [self indexPathsInSection:section];
          [Table deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:paths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

         }
   else {
            NSArray *paths = [self indexPathsInSection:section];
            [Table insertRowsAtIndexPaths:paths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];
             }


   [Table endUpdates];
   [Table reloadData];
   }
- (NSInteger)numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

if(kMAX_SECTION_ROWS[section] == 0)
{
    return 1;
}
else
{
    return kMAX_SECTION_ROWS[section];
}
//return 0;
 }

  - (void)toggleSection:(id)sender {
   NSLog(@"button %d is clicked.",[sender tag]);
int i = [sender tag];
if(!isSectionExpanded[i]){
    NSLog(@"expanded");
    hString[i].arrowImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"downarrow.png"];
}
else {
    NSLog(@"not expanded");
    hString[i].arrowImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"arrowgrean.png"];
}

[self toggle:&isSectionExpanded[i] section:i];
 }
```

when i run the code in IOS 5 it shows me error

```
     Assertion failure in -[_UITableViewUpdateSupport    _computeRowUpdates],/SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-1912.3/UITableViewSupport.m:386
```

if any clue then reply thanks

Comment: What have you done so far to track down the bug?

Comment: i had tried to check for the no. of sections in the table view and the n at run time i got the rows count for the sections and it is working well in IOS 3.0 and 4.0....

Comment: thanks but now i got the different way to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hi friends i have got the blog where i found the source for the same which works on every ios so any one want it just go to :
http://soulwithmobiletechnology.blogspot.com/2011/06/how-does-uitableviewcell-reorder.html

i think this saves your lots of time
thanks

Comment: I am also faced same issue but didn't get any help from your suggested link.Can you post some other link to solve this.

Comment: Ya i was also not be able to solve that issue so, I used the code from the above link and able to do in one of my last project. you can also use from there.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe iOS5 is more picky about the things you say. When you write

```
if(kMAX_SECTION_ROWS[section] == 0)
```

you should really return 0 and not 1 (or else return a section header somewhere else).

Comment: Thank you for your support but i have got the another way to make it happen